# Undesired download of Baidu Browser

Tags: security, downloading, lookout

new Android user with the world's most low end tablet, Azpen A727.  I'm enjoying learning about Android and have killed off most of the bloatware...but twice now "Baidu Browser" has been downloaded without my request.  I'm using the bloatware security app Lookout now.  Is there a way to find out what is requesting these downloads, stop it, or block it?  I'm open to using a different security app.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Though "killed off most of the bloatware" suggests as much, I'd better make sure before posting "the wrong answer" :)

Comment: Not yet, but I plan to.  So far I've just deleted and/or disabled unwanted apps.

Comment: OK, as you plan to: Would an answer requiring root be acceptable?

Comment: OK – see below. There would be much more to say on that app, but that'd be too much here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using *LBE Security Manager* for a while now (as the "lite version", *LBE Privacy Guard*, is no longer continued and soesn't work with Android 4.1 and above). I first felt it a bit, umm, over-loaded – but it runs decently (no battery drain or performance issues), and after disabling half of its features I don't need, I'm pretty satisfied with it.

While my primary taget was its privacy protection (revoking app permissions), LBE-SM ships with a load of other features. One of them **watches over app installs, and places a note in your notification area when one happened. You then can follow that (tap the notification), and blacklist the app. LBE-SM then blocks all future installations of it.**

There are a bunch of additional features, many of them primarily targeted at the Chinese market (cloud anti-virus, call blocker, etc), a basic firewall (block internet-access per app and interface, i.e. separately for WiFi and mobile data), plus more.

It's a closed-source app of Chinese origin, which might sound suspect at first. But there's a huge follow-ship at XDA (and Xposed, and elsewhere), so it can't be that bad ;) Unfortunately, the app version available at Google Play is Chinese only (you won't be able to understand a thing if you're not used to Chinese). But there are ways, like localized [English, Vietnamese](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46695347&postcount=2010), [German](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37188801&postcount=782), and other language's versions at XDA - or the [LBE Xposed Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.xda_drm.lbe51_translation_ww) to be used with the playstore version, to get a usable installation. I'm using the linked English variant from XDA for a while, and already found it updated a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks for the LBE link, just downloaded from XDA. Was looking for English variant, but I didn't want to use the Xposed module.

Comment: Both have their pros and cons. Using Xposed, you could use the Playstore version and automatically update it from Play. Using the XDA version, you'll have to keep care not to update from Play. Besides, I'd recommend to de-activate the software update check in LBE – can get pretty annoying getting update infos for all your apps in Chinese ;)

Comment: Sounds like what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Always glad to help :)